# Ruby how to check if strings in one array is an object attribute in another array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays.

One is named foods, it is an array of strings.

The other is named dataList. It is an array of objects that contain an attribute named name.

What I need to do is check if the names in the array foods is present in the dataList. So that means all the items in foods needs to be equal to one of the name attributes in dataList.

I know how to check arrays if both arrays contained the same type of data. But I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we don't care about the order of the elements nor about the number of times an element is present, we can do this easily with Sets.

```
require 'set'

foods_set = Set.new(foods)

attribute_names_set = Set.new
dataList.each do |d|
  attribute_names_set << d.name
end

return foods_set == attribute_names_set
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm new to Ruby and I didn't think about sets. I'll read up more on sets.

Again thanks for the help!

Comment: This solution works. the only thing I needed to change was        return foods_set == attribute_names_set

should be
return foods_set.subset? attribute_names_set

Thanks for the help!